# Как правильнее делать, чтобы __init__ задействовался у примесей

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня вариант такой:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("first")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("second")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__()
        B.__init__()
```

Но тут с зависимостями проблема. Через `super` было бы веселее. Что скажете, такое решение подходящее?

Comment: Чё-то я про «супер» не понял, чем он не подошёл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно только один вызов `super().__init__()` использовать, если классы написаны в кооперативном стиле, поддерживающим множественное наследование:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        print("A", a)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class B:
    def __init__(self, b, **kwargs):
        print("B", b)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class C(A, B):
    pass

C(a=1, b=2)
```

Вывод:

```
A 1
B 2
```

Вызваны оба родительских метода в A и B классах, даже не определяя специализированный `C.__init__` метод.

Классы созданы, следуя [трём правилам](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/):

- метод, вызываемый `super()` существует (`__init__` метод у всех классов есть, включая `object`)
- вызываемые методы совместимы (поэтому `**kwargs` используется, чтобы адаптировать разные аргументы)
- каждое определение метода использует `super()` для вызова родительских методов.

Если поменять порядок наследования, то и порядок вызовов также изменится:

```
class D(B, A):
    pass

D(a=2, b=1)
```

Вывод:

```
B 1
A 2
```

Порядок противоположный первому примеру.

Если нужно явно определить дочерний `__init__`, то опять таки: одного super() вызова достаточно:

```
class E(A, B):
    def __init__(self, e, **kwargs):
      print("E", e)
      super().__init__(**kwargs)

E(a=2, b=3, e=1)
```

Вывод:

```
E 1
A 2
B 3
```

Эта техника поддерживает случаи когда один и тот же класс несколько раз встречается в иерархии («ромб»). [C3 алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) используется для линеаризации порядка вызовов родительских методов, чтобы найти [MRO в Питоне](http://python-history.blogspot.ru/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html):

```
class F(C, E):
    pass

F(a=2, b=3, e=1)
```

Вывод:

```
E 1
A 2
B 3
```

Не смотря на то, что классы `А`, `B` дважды предками класса `F` являются, соответствующие `__init__` методы только по одному разу вызываются, благодаря линеаризации. [Порядок вызовов родительских `__init__` методов](https://ideone.com/v35jA6):

```
print(*[klass.__name__ for klass in F.mro()], sep=' -> ')
#    F -> C -> E -> A -> B -> object
```

[image: mro of F]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        print("A", a)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class B:
    def __init__(self, b, **kwargs):
        print("B", b)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class C(A, B):
    pass

class D(B, A):
    pass
    
class E(A, B):
    def __init__(self, e, **kwargs):
        print("E", e)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class F(C, E):
    pass


C(a=1, b=2)
D(a=4, b=3)
E(a=6, b=7, e=5)
F(a=9, b=10, e=8)
print(*[klass.__name__ for klass in F.__mro__], sep=' -> ')
</script></body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Например можно поступить так:

```
In [30]: class A:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         print("first")
    ...:
    ...: class B:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         print("second")
    ...:
    ...: class C(A, B):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         super(C, self).__init__()
    ...:         super(A, self).__init__()
    ...:

In [31]: obj = C()
first
second
```

[Детальное пояснение.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Чтобы понимать более детально что происходит, стоит почитать про ["Ромбовидное наследование"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

Вот достаточно понятное объяснение:

По сути, объект класса `super` запоминает аргументы переданные ему в момент инициализации и при вызове любого метода (`super().__init__(self)` в примере выше) проходит по списку линеаризации класса второго аргумента (`self.__class__.__mro__`), пытаясь вызвать этот метод по очереди для всех классов, следующих за классом в первом аргументе (класс C), передавая в качестве параметра первый аргумент (`self`). Т.е. для нашего случая:

```
self.__class__.__mro__ = [C, A, B]
super(C, self).__init__() => A.__init__(self)
super(A, self).__init__() => B.__init__(self)
```

[Источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/62203/).

Comment: Я там не понял. Перевод тугой.

Comment: Про ромбовидное наследование я в курсе, спасибо. Сначала поиск в ширину, потом в глубину. Вроде так в третьем питоне.

Comment: Статья хорошая. Раскрывает нужный вопрос полностью. Даже описали возможные проблемы, которые появятся, если использовать способ указанный в вопросе. Я о таком подозревал. Спасибо.

Comment: лучше слушать контрибуторов языка в таких вопросах.
Например здесь с русским переводом:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61UuKJRl2m0